# SQL table trailing space cause errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had an error in my C# code and after debugging found that 
this is because on entry in a table has a trailing space. 
For example 'aaa '

Now in my C# code try to set a Selected values of a combo box to this(combobox as an item with value of 'aaa' and this fails.

Clearly The solution is to fix the DB 'aaa '

Now I go to DB

and do this :

```
Select * from mytable 
where Name='aaa'
```

I get Name `'aaa'`

```
Select * from mytable 
where Name='aaa        '
```

Again I get Name `'aaa'`

```
Select len(name) from My table
where name ='aaa'
```

I get `3`

My question is: how by querying the table I know it has an extra space for 'aaa '?

Comment: This is how it works in Sql Server.

Comment: So there no way I look at a table data and check if it has trailing spaces?!!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626    SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, <Comparison Predicate>, General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.

Comment: Holly molly! This is bad. The problem is i look at the table entry looks like 'aaa' but it clearly has a trailing space.

Comment: Use `DATALENGTH` instead of `LEN`.  `LEN` does not count trailing spaces.  Also, trailing spaces are ignored for in T-SQL compares.

Comment: That all for providing fast solution to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL server [len](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function excludes trailing blanks.

Consider using the [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) (Transact-SQL) function which does not trim the string.

So you can check if `datalength(column) <> datalength(rtrim(column))` to find if it contains trailing spaces.

Note: if processing a unicode string, `DATALENGTH` will return twice the number of characters.

Comment: Yes. That's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Giorgi Nakeuri has explained, 'a    ' and 'a' are considered equal. But you can easily find trailing spaces with `LIKE`:

```
select * from mytable where name like '% ';
```

And here is how to update:

```
update mytable set name = rtrim(name) where name like '% ';
```